# foreach para matrices en javascript

Tags: javascript, php

tengo una duda:

¿Se puede usar el foreach para encontrar valores en una matriz?

Tengo la siguiente matriz que creo en php y la lleno con valores de una Base de datos:

```
    $rspta=$obj->mostrar2($id);
    $data = array();

    while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()) {
        
      $data[]=array(
        
        "0"     =>  "2",
        "1"     =>  $reg->valor1, 
        "2"     =>  $reg->valor2,
        "3"     =>  $reg->valor3
        
      );

        }

    $rspta=$obj->mostrar3($id);
    while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()) {
        
      $data[]=array(
        
        "0"     =>  "2",
        "1"     =>  $reg->valor1, 
        "2"     =>  $reg->valor2,
        "3"     =>  $reg->valor3


        );

        }
```

Donde "mostrar2" y "mostrar3" son sentencias SQL:

```
public function mostrar2($folio){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE folio='$folio'";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
```

```
public function mostrar3($folio){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE folio='$folio'";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
```

Y esto se recibe en un archivo js:

```
data2=JSON.parse(data);
```

Ahora, como esta matriz se llena con datos de una base de datos, hay varios arrays que me llegan con valor de `[x][0] = 1` y de `[x][0] = 2`, valores que uso como identificador para saber que tipo de datos son (por ejemplo, si `[x][0] = 1` los datos son autos y si `[x][0] = 2` los datos son motos)

Mi pregunta es:
¿Cómo puedo saber cuantos `[x][0] = 1` tengo en la matriz?

Intenté hacerlo con 2 ciclos for, pero no me funciona correctamente.
Estuve leyendo y parece que foreach podría ser la solución, pero no he conseguido hacer que funcione para una matriz.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como podría funcionar?

Comment: "Intenté hacerlo con..." `<=` aquí es donde incluyes en tu pregunta el código correspondiente y explicas por qué no funciona correctamente. Errores? Resultados incorrectos? Ponlo todo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no veo una pregunta concreta te cuento como funcionan las forEach y reduce (que puede interesarte para lo que planteas de contar elementos)
Una solución para contar elementos con forEach:

```
matriz = [1,2,5,2,7,2,1]
arg = {val:2, total:0}
matriz.forEach(function(v){
      if(v==this.val){
         this.total++;
        }
     }, arg)
console.log("Hay "+arg.total+" del número "+arg.val
```

Así podrías contar el número de elementos de la matriz que cumplen una cierta condición, por ejemplo todos lo elementos que sean 2 o que sean 1.
Espero que se adapte a tu problema o te sirva de base para encontrar una solución